# Class Cast Exception - Rarely crashing my application

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I have recently released an app and I am currently getting approximately 5k sessions per day. Starting this morning I have noticed that Crashlytics has reported approximately 10 crashes (Unique users) in the last 2 hours due to the following issue:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 

android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.**********.**********.AnalyticsApplication
```

I implemented google analytics according to their documentation: [Google Analytics Doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

As such my manifest looks like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/application_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

The issue occurs in the onCreate method of my launcher activity:

```
// Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
screen_id = "Initialize";
```

I am wondering if I have been approaching this incorrectly. I find it strange that it has been working without issue until today. Has anyone else ran into an issue like this before? Due to it only occurring for a fraction of my user base I have not been able to reproduce the issue.

Any insight into the cause of this issue would be greatly appreciated, it is not good having the app crash on the user as they open it.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? I also see it randomly and only on android 7+. Thanks

Comment: @vandzi Hey there, sorry for the delayed reply. Unfortunately I have not found a way to solve this. I have been doing a few pre-caution checks which seems to have reduced the number of crashes significantly.

Still no 100% fix yet :(

edit: I seem to be getting it on 6 and 7, however 7 is much more prevalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the full package instead of using

android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"

like

android:name="com.blabla.AnalyticsApplication"

Comment: I use full package name